# Latency issue with Tensorflow cuDNN model execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch

I am having problems with a cuDNN RNN model I am trying to train on a set of natural language explanations and embeddings for the semantic parsing of texts. Here is what my RNN model architecture looks like on a simplified level:

```
class Cudnn_RNN:

    def __init__(self, num_layers, num_units, mode="lstm", keep_prob=1.0, is_train=None, scope="cudnn_rnn"):
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.rnns = []
        self.mode = mode
        if mode == "gru":
            rnn = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU
        elif mode == "lstm":
            rnn = tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnLSTM
        else:
            raise Exception("Unknown mode for rnn")
        for layer in range(num_layers):
            rnn_fw = rnn(1, num_units)
            rnn_bw = rnn(1, num_units)
            self.rnns.append((rnn_fw, rnn_bw, ))

    def __call__(self, inputs, seq_len, keep_prob=1.0, is_train=None, concat_layers=True):
        outputs = [tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])]
        for layer in range(self.num_layers):
            rnn_fw, rnn_bw = self.rnns[layer]
            output = dropout(outputs[-1], keep_prob=keep_prob, is_train=is_train)
            with tf.variable_scope("fw_{}".format(layer)):
                out_fw, state_fw = rnn_fw(output)
            with tf.variable_scope("bw_{}".format(layer)):
                inputs_bw = tf.reverse_sequence(output, seq_lengths=seq_len, seq_axis=0, batch_axis=1)
                out_bw, state_bw = rnn_bw(inputs_bw)
                out_bw = tf.reverse_sequence(out_bw, seq_lengths=seq_len, seq_axis=0, batch_axis=1)
            outputs.append(tf.concat([out_fw, out_bw], axis=2))
        if concat_layers is True:
            res = tf.concat(outputs[1:], axis=2)
        else:
            res = outputs[-1]
        res = tf.transpose(res, [1, 0, 2])
        state_fw = tf.squeeze(state_fw[0], [0])
        state_bw = tf.squeeze(state_bw[0], [0])
        state = tf.concat([state_fw, state_bw], axis=1)
        return res, state
```

The model is set up such that after data is loaded, it goes through pretraining, training, and then evaluation. For some reason the data is being loaded with no issues, but as soon as the model starts running it gets stuck, not even making it to the pretraining phase. Here is the data loading and execution code (model executes up until just before `print('---Pretrain-----')`:

```
def pseudo_labeling(config, data):
    word2idx_dict, fixed_emb, traiable_emb, train_data, dev_data, test_data,pretrain_data,pretrain_data2 = data

    pretrain_test_data = (pretrain_data[0][:config.pretrain_test_size],pretrain_data[1][:config.pretrain_test_size],pretrain_data[2][:config.pretrain_test_size,:])
    pretrain_data = (pretrain_data[0][config.pretrain_test_size:config.pretrain_test_size+config.pretrain_train_size],pretrain_data[1][config.pretrain_test_size:config.pretrain_test_size+config.pretrain_train_size],pretrain_data[2][config.pretrain_test_size:config.pretrain_test_size+config.pretrain_train_size,:])

    lfs = get_lfs(config, word2idx_dict)
    identifier = "_{}".format(config.tag)

    with tf.variable_scope("models", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        regex = Pat_Match(config)
        match = Soft_Match(config,lfs['lfs'],np.array(lfs['rels'],np.float32),lfs['keywords'],lfs['keywords_rels'], lfs['raw_keywords'],mat=((fixed_emb, traiable_emb, )), word2idx_dict=word2idx_dict, pseudo=True)

    sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
    sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    if os.path.exists('labeled_data.pkl'):
        with open('labeled_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            labeled_data = pickle.load(f)
        with open('unlabeled_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            unlabeled_data = pickle.load(f)
        with open('weights.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            lfs["weights"] = pickle.load(f)
    else:
        with open('exp2pat.json','r') as f:
            exp2pat = json.load(f)
        exp2pat = {int(key):val for key,val in exp2pat.items()}
        lab_d = []
        unlab_d = []

        tacred_labeled = []
        tacred_unlabeled = []
        labeled_data = []
        unlabeled_data = []
        idxx = -1

        idx2rel = {val:key for key,val in constant.LABEL_TO_ID.items()}

        for x in tqdm(train_data):
            idxx+=1
            batch = [x["phrase"]]
            res, pred = regex.match(batch)
            lfs["weights"] += res[0]
            new_dict = {}
            if np.amax(res) > 0:

                x["rel"] = pred.tolist()[0]
                x["logic_form"] = np.argmax(res, axis=1).tolist()[0]
                new_dict['tokens'] = x['phrase'].token
                new_dict['start'] = min(x['phrase'].subj_posi,x['phrase'].obj_posi)+1
                new_dict['end'] = max(x['phrase'].subj_posi,x['phrase'].obj_posi)-1
                new_dict['rel'] = pred.tolist()[0]
                try:
                    new_dict['pat'] = exp2pat[np.argmax(res, axis=1).tolist()[0]]
                    lab_d.append(new_dict)
                except:
                    new_dict['pat'] = -1
                    unlab_d.append(new_dict)
                tacred_labeled.append((idxx,idx2rel[x['rel']]))
                labeled_data.append(x)
            else:
                tacred_unlabeled.append(idxx)
                new_dict['tokens'] = x['phrase'].token
                new_dict['start'] = min(x['phrase'].subj_posi,x['phrase'].obj_posi)+1
                new_dict['end'] = max(x['phrase'].subj_posi,x['phrase'].obj_posi)-1
                new_dict['rel'] = pred.tolist()[0]
                new_dict['pat']=-1
                x["rel"] = 0
                unlab_d.append(new_dict)
                unlabeled_data.append(x)

        new_weight = np.array([elem for i, elem in enumerate(list(lfs['weights'])) if i in exp2pat],np.float32)
        new_weight = new_weight/np.sum(new_weight)
        lfs["weights"] = lfs["weights"] / np.sum(lfs["weights"])

        with open('tacred_labeled.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(tacred_labeled,f)

        with open('tacred_unlabeled.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(tacred_unlabeled,f)

        with open('labeled_data.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(labeled_data,f)
        with open('unlabeled_data.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(unlabeled_data,f)
        with open('weights.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(lfs["weights"], f)

        with open('lab_d.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(lab_d,f)
        with open('unlab_d.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(unlab_d,f)
        with open('weights_d.pkl','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(new_weight,f)

    random.shuffle(unlabeled_data)

    print('unlabdel data:',str(len(unlabeled_data)),'labeled data:',str(len(labeled_data)))

    dev_history, test_history = [], []
    dev_history2, test_history2 = [], []

    with tf.Session(config=sess_config) as sess:

        lr = float(config.init_lr)
        writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(config.log_dir + identifier)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        print('---Pretrain-----')
        for epoch in range(config.pretrain_epoch):
            loss_list,pretrain_loss_lis,sim_loss_lis = [],[],[]
            for batch in get_pretrain_batch(config, pretrain_data, word2idx_dict):
                pretrain_loss_prt,sim_loss_prt,loss,_ = sess.run([match.pretrain_loss,match.sim_loss,match.pretrain_loss_v2,match.pre_train_op],feed_dict={match.pretrain_sents: batch['sents'], match.pretrain_pats: batch['pats'],match.pretrain_labels: batch['labels'],match.is_train:True})
                loss_list.append(loss)
                pretrain_loss_lis.append(pretrain_loss_prt)
                sim_loss_lis.append(sim_loss_prt)
            print("{} epoch:".format(str(epoch)))
            print("loss:{} pretrain_loss:{} sim_loss:{}".format(str(np.mean(loss_list)),str(np.mean(pretrain_loss_lis)),str(np.mean(sim_loss_lis))))
            pred_labels = []
            goldens = []
            prt_id = 0
            for batch in get_pretrain_batch(config,pretrain_data2,word2idx_dict,shuffle=False):
                prt_id+=1
                pp,ppp,pred_label = sess.run([match.prt_loss,match.prt_pred,match.pretrain_pred_labels],feed_dict={match.pretrain_sents: batch['sents'], match.pretrain_pats: batch['pats'],match.is_train:False,match.pretrain_labels: batch['labels']})
                pred_label = list(pred_label)
                golden = list(np.reshape(batch['labels'],[-1]))
                assert len(golden)==len(pred_label)
                pred_labels.extend(pred_label)
                goldens.extend(golden)
            p,r,f = f_score(pred_labels,goldens)
            print('PRF:',(p,r,f))
            if p>0.9 and r>0.9:
                break
            print('\n')
```

Here are my system specifications:
Tensorflow version: 1.14.0 (w/ GPU support)
Operating System: Linux 9.12
OS Distribution: Debian
OS Architecture: x86_64
Python version: 3.7.6
NLTK version: 3.4.5
CUDA version: 10.0
cuDNN version: 7.4.2
NVIDIA graphics card: Tesla T4
NVIDIA driver version: 410.104
Compiler version: GCC 6.3.0

If anyone would like to share their thoughts on why my model is unable to properly execute to the pretraining phase and beyond, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: are you using both tensorflow and pytorch?

Comment: yes, but I'm using pytorch mostly for semantic data parsing while the model itself is mostly tensorflow